# Solve a differential equation using the power series method

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

#### Problem

By assuming a power series solution of the form $$y(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} c_mx^m , \quad c_0 \not =0 $$

Show that the equation  $ 2y'+xy=x            $
has general solution $y(x)=1+Ae^{-x^2/4}$ where A is a constant.

[Hint: you may use without proof the fact that $$  e^{ax^2} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{(ax^2)^n}{n!}         $$

#### Progress

I'm genuinely stuck, I've worked out $y'$ and substituted it into the equation $2y′+xy=x$ however not to sure where to go from there?

Comment: Can you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: im genuinely stuck, i've worked out $y'$ and substituted it into the equation $2y'+xy=x$ however not to sure where to go from there??

Comment: @freak_warrior could you help me with the first step??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$2\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}{mc_m x^{m-1}}+\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{c_m x^{m+1}}=x$$
$$2c_1+2\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}{mc_m x^{m-1}}+\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{c_m x^{m+1}}=x$$
$$2c_1+2\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{(m+2)c_{m+2} x^{m+1}}+\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{c_m x^{m+1}}=x$$
$$2c_1+\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}{(2(m+2)c_{m+2}+{c_m}) x^{m+1}}=x$$,

so we have $2c_1 = 0$, $2(2c_2)+c_0 = 1$, $2((m+2)c_{m+2})+c_m = 0$ for $m>0$,

so $c_k=0$ for odd $k$,

$c_0\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$
$c_2=\frac{1-c_0}{4}=\frac{1-c_0}{4*1!}$,

$c_4=\frac{-c_2}{8}=\frac{-(1-c_0)}{32}=\frac{-1+c_0}{32}=\frac{-1+c_0}{4^2*2!}$,

$c_6=\frac{-c_4}{12}=\frac{1-c_0}{32*12}=\frac{1-c_0}{4^3*3!}$, and so on...

I'll leave it to you to get an explicit formula for $c_k$ for even $k$

now write $c_0 = 1+(-1+c_0)$,

With all these, try to express put the explicit representation for $y$.

You will also need to substitute $a=\frac{1}{4}$ into your hint to get your desired solution

Comment: for $c_2 = \frac{1-C_0}{4} $ where did you the $1$ from?? ive tried working out each step from the start and i have $c_2 = \frac{-c_0}{4} $

Comment: when you match the coefficients of $x$, you will get $4c_2+c_0=1$.@Xian

Comment: why does it $=1$ surely we consider it as a homogeneous to start with so we let it $=0$??

Comment: Consider the coefficient of $x$ on both LHS and RHS, they have to be the same @Xian

Comment: oh okay, so we dont let the LHS$=0$ as we would normally do when we have a inhomogeneous DE?

Comment: Yes! Can you take it from here? @Xian

Comment: I shall try :) Thanks

Comment: hiya, i've worked out the explicit formula for $C_k$ for even $k$ however, i'm not sure how im supposed to go from this to the explicit representation for $y$???

Comment: Did you get 
$$y=1+(c_0-1)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-x^2)^k}{4^kk!}$$? @Xian

Comment: i've worked out that $$C_{2k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1-C_0)(-1)^{k+1}}{4^kk!}$$ but im not sure how to get $y$ from this? @freak_warrior

Comment: just put your derived expressions of $c_{k}$ into $$y(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} c_mx^m$$

Comment: in this expression what does $m = ?$

Comment: could you help me with a little more information please

Comment: In this case the index $m$ is just a dummy variable, you can replace it with other variables, like $k$.

Comment: i dont get it, so what am i supposed to do with the $C_{2k}$??